# Bootstrap 5 - Dropdown AND Tooltip on Button?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Trying to add a tooltip to a btn (or any other tag) that already uses data-bs-toggle - the best result I can get is with the following:

```
function xmdEnableTooltips() {
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call ( document.querySelectorAll ( '[data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip"]' ) )
let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map ( function ( tooltipTriggerEl ) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip ( tooltipTriggerEl )
} ) }


    <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="sandbox-tooltip"
        class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip"
        data-bs-placement="right"
        title="tooltip info ...">Tooltip Button
    </button>
```

Results:

- on hover, tooltip displays
- on first click, nothing happens
- on second click, dropdown items display
- on click away from btn, tooltip disappears, but dropdown items do not

Other:
I tried:

- wrapping the btn in a div and adding the tooltip code to that
- adding a span inside the btn with the tooltip code
  neither worked.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thx

Comment: From accessibility perspective not possible according to this comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33940#issuecomment-838454777

Comment: Thx for the link. IMHO, this is a big miss - it's due to the way tooltip ( and popovers) are implemented as another variant of bs-data-toggle, instead of having their own property. Almost all the tooltips/popovers I would use are on user actions (e.g. buttons, kinks, etc.). Kinda defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW...

1. as @Supportic noted, adding a popover to any button (or other tag) that already uses a bs-data-toggle is a non-starter.  But why would anyone want a button to trigger a popover...?
2. However, the following works fine for hovering over text (or other tags) - popover shows and hides correctly.

   data-bs-trigger="hover"

Comment: But it breaks the dropdown functionality as it returns the following error "Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.dropdown."

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer does not in fact answer the asked question, but provides an alternative solution, which is not always an option - here is how to enable both dropdown and tooltip on an element in Bootstrap 5:

```html
<!-- Add Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Add Bootstrap Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<!-- Some explanatory wrapping -->
<div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3">
<div class="container-fluid py-5">
   <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Bootstrap 5 Tooltip with Dropdown Example</h1>
   <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Bootstrap gives you easy and powerful way to accomplish mostly anything.</p>

<p>Here we can use any of the 4 possible drop*:  <strong>dropdown</strong>, <strong>dropup</strong>, <strong>dropstart</strong>, or <strong>dropend</strong>.

<!-- The IMPORTANT STUFF START -->
<div class="btn-group dropup" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="Click the icon to show dropdown.">
  <i class="bi bi-info-circle-fill"
     data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
     data-bs-popper-config='{"strategy":"fixed"}'
     aria-expanded="false"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="table-responsive m-2">
    <table class="table table-secondary table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3, Col 1</td><td>Row 3, Col 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The IMPORTANT STUFF END -->


</div>
</div>


<!-- Add Popper & Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  // Enable BS Tooltips 
  const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
  const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
});
</script>
```